On the intersection of nested sequence of nice sets
Let $\{H_n\}$ be a sequence of non-empty closed, bounded and convex sets in a Banach space $X$ with $H_{n+1}\subseteq H_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Denote $\delta(A)= \sup\{\|x-y\|: x, y\in A\},$ the diameter of the set $A,$ where $A$ is a bounded subset of $X.$ If $\delta(H_n)\to r$ for some positive real $r,$ then can we say that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n$ is non-empty?
My Approach: I do not have any clue how to start. If we assume the contrary, i.e., if $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n =\emptyset,$ then how do we proceed? Where do we get the contradiction, if at all the result is true?
Could not find a duplicate problem here.

Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about how to ask a good question.

If $X$ is reflexive, this is true by Mazur’s theorem and the fact that (norm) bounded weakly closed sets are weakly compact in a reflexive space. I do not know whether reflexivity is necessary.
